# Conditional pipelining in Bash

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a filter that I want to enable optionally and I wonder how can I do this in bash in a clean way.

```
FILTER="| sort" # also can be empty
ls $FILTER | cat
```

This code does not work because it will call `ls` with `|` and `sort` as parameters.

How can I do this correctly? Please mind that I am trying to avoid creating `if` blocks in order to keep the code easy to maintain (my piping chain is considerable more complex than this example)

Comment: Are these filters going to receive any kind of parameters?

Comment: One way of living dangerously is to use `eval`.  That can be safe if you are completely in control of the string that is evaluated; if the user can supply input to the string that is evaluated, it is a disaster waiting to happen.  Where you expected them to say `cat`, maybe they said `cat; mv $HOME/.profile $HOME/.junk` or something even more horrendous (and probably irreversible, or at least non-trivially reversible).  Using `eval`, therefore, is dangerous.  Nevertheless, it exists, and it can be useful.

Answer (score 4):

What you have in mind doesn't work because the variable expansion happens *after* the syntax has been parsed.

You can do something like this:

```
foo_cmd | if [ "$order" = "desc" ] ; then
    sort -r
else
    sort
fi | if [ "$cut" = "on" ] ; then
    cut -f1
else
    cat
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the command and execute it in a different shell.

```
FILTER="| sort" # create your filter here
# ls $FILTER | cat  <-- this won't work
bash -c "ls $FILTER | cat"

# or create the entire command and execute (which, i think, is more clean)
cmd="ls $FILTER | cat"
bash -c "$cmd"
```

If you select this approach, you must make sure the command is syntactically valid and does exactly what you intend, instead of doing something disastrous.

Comment: This would come with all the disadvantages of dynamic code execution and should be avoided.

Comment: @hek2mgl I agree, but as I understood, the OP is trying to do exactly the same by applying a filter defined in a variable while not willing to use conditional constructs. He must make sure the command is valid by some other means.