# How to conditionally add a pipeline element in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, pipeline, conditional-execution

I need to form a pipeline of various commands. Some elements of the pipeline, or sequences of elements, are only relevant when some condition holds. Now, I could write:

```
if [[ $whatever ]]; then
   cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4
else
   cmd1 | cmd4
fi
```

but that means repeating `cmd1` and `cmd4`, plus, there may be several conditions and I don't want to write nested if's. So, I tried writing this:

```
if [[ $whatever ]]; then
    pipeline_segment="| cmd2 | cmd3"
else
    pipeline_segment=""
fi

cmd1 ${pipeline_segment} | cmd4
```

but - the pipe symbol was not interpreted as an instruction to use a pipe.

How do I have bash execute the pipeline I want it too?

Note: You may assume a bash version of 4 or higher, but only if you must.

Comment: `eval "cmd1 ${pipeline_segment} | cmd4"` maybe?

Comment: in the same vein as `eval`, or a compound command being submitted to `ssh`: `bash -c "cmd1 ${pipeline_segment} | cmd4"` (keeping in mind the potential need to escape embedded double quotes, etc)

Comment: Very similar: [Conditional pipelining in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690174/conditional-pipelining-in-bash)

Answer (score 8):

Your attempt fails because special symbols lose their syntactical value after expansion. `eval` is a way, but as we know it is prone to code injection so it is best avoided. We can try

```
cmd1 |
if [ condition ]; then
   cmd2 | cmd3
else
   cat
fi | 
cmd4
```

Though I'd love to skip `cat`, I couldn't find a way. Real example:

```
echo XYZABC |
if true; then
   tr Y B | tr Z C
else
   cat
fi | 
tr X A
```

outputs `ABCABC` and changing the condition to `false` outputs `AYZABC`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having `cat` there. One can obviate the overhead by enabling loadable built-in `tee` and using it instead if that's an issue.

Comment: I had considered using `cat`. But - won't that incur a significant performance penalty for large files?

Comment: @oguzismail: What is a "loadable built-in tee"?

Comment: @einpoklum Bash comes with various loadable builtins, `tee` is one of them. On my system they are stored in `/usr/lib/bash` and I can do `enable -f /usr/lib/bash/tee tee` and have `tee` as a builtin command.

Comment: @oguzismail: Oh, that's a nice idea then. Can you make it into an answer?

Comment: @einpoklum It may be, but presumably your other commands are considerably more complex than `cat` (at least if they are text-processing commands).

Answer (score 6):

I presume you're not wanting to repeat anything because they are big gnarly commands. In that case, use functions to encapsulate them:

```sh
cmd1() { some big long command with many options and arguments; }
cmd2() { similar; }
... and so on
```

The you can literally use this

```sh
if [[ $whatever ]]; then
   cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4
else
   cmd1 | cmd4
fi
```

---

or, push the `whatever` condition into the functions:

```sh
cmd2 () { 
    if [[ whatever ]]; then
        the big long command
    else
        cat
    fi
}
cmd3() {
    if [[ whatever ]]; then
        the other big long command
    else
        cat
    fi
}
```

Then, you're left with simply

```sh
cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 | cmd4
```